# Количество повторяющихся символов в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, необходимо посчитать кол-во повторяющихся символов в ней и вернуть результат в виде двумерного массива в порядке появления символов.

```
'abracadabra' == [['a', 5], ['b', 2], ['r', 2], ['c', 1], ['d', 1]]
```

Написал такой код:

```js
const str = 'abracadabra';

let orderedCount = text => {
  return Object.entries(text.split('').reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {}));
}

console.log(orderedCount(str))
```

К сожалению, в случае строки, состоящей из цифр, он их в результате сортирует.
Как избавиться от этой сортировки?

Comment: Сделайте регулярной.

Comment: Так ваш код не работает даже на обычных строках, при чем тут цифры? Вы же не сортируете получаемый массив.

Comment: На обычных строках результат показывает как надо(в порядке появления символов, как в примере). А вот в случае строки с цифрами, они сортируются в порядке возрастания

Comment: регулярные выражения еще не изучал, без них как-то можно?

Comment: @DM 400, да, я что-то решил, что по частоте появления выводим.

Comment: @DM 400, в любом случае, насколько я помню, порядок `Object.entries` может разниться от браузера к браузеру.

Comment: к сожалению они сортируются внутри самого объекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что современные браузеры сортируют порядок числовых ключей в объекте при обходе.

Что бы этого избежать, не используйте объект, используйте `Map`.

Например:

```js
const str = '4321';

let orderedCount = text => {
  return Array.from(text.split('').reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc.set(el, (acc.get(el) || 0) + 1);
    return acc;
  }, new Map()));
}

console.log(orderedCount(str));
```

Comment: _Дело в том. что современные браузеры сортируют порядок ключей в объекте._ - это неверное утверждение

Comment: @Grundy Ключи сортируются при выводе. Где-то было в спецификации написано - вы мне сами и давали ссылку где-то полгода назад.

Comment: Они не сортируются. При обходе исключение делается только для числовых ключей, которые могут быть индексами массива, остальные ключи обходятся в порядке добавления в объект. Из ответа сейчас следует, будто все ключи как-то сортируются - это не так

Comment: Почему неправильно работает даже на строке abracadabra, если вывод соответствует ожидаемому?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Исправил ответ :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваши ответы, очень помогли)